# How to properly connect two functions in python?

Tags: python, function, oop, pyqt5

I have problem with connecting two functions to each other in my small program.
I am using PyQt5 and PyPDF2 modules.I would like to link two pdf files into one.
In my program I have 3 buttons:

- btnPlik1 - browse 1st file (connected to function openFile1)
- btnPlik2 - browse 2nd file (connected to function openFile2)
- btnPlik3 - 'start' - run program (connected to function laczeniePdf)

Functions work separately but when I would like to connect them by clicking 'Start'(btnPlik3) my program crashes. Below is my code:

```
def openFile1(self):
    pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
    print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
    if pathFileName:
        print("Wybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
        g = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
        return g

def openFile2(self):
    pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
    print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
    if pathFileName:
        print("Wybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
        h = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
        return h

def laczeniePdf(self,g, h):
    readerLinkPage1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(g, 'rb'))
    readerLinkPage2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(h, 'rb'))
    writerLinkPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    OutputFile = open('FinalOutput.pdf', 'wb')
    writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage1)
    writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage2)
    writerLinkPage.write(OutputFile)
    OutputFile.close()
```

I am looking forward for your hints and advises

EDIT:

```
Here is code of class we are talking about(it is separate window in my program)

class Ui_PolaczPliki(object):
    def setupUi(self, PolaczPliki):
        PolaczPliki.setObjectName("PolaczPliki")
        PolaczPliki.resize(295, 113)
        self.btnPlik1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 91, 41))
        self.btnPlik1.setObjectName("btnPlik1")
        self.btnPlik1.clicked.connect(self.openFile1)
        self.btnPlik2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 40, 91, 41))
        self.btnPlik2.setObjectName("btnPlik2")
        self.btnPlik2.clicked.connect(self.openFile2)
        self.btnPlik3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 80, 40, 20))
        self.btnPlik3.setObjectName("btnPlik3")
        self.btnPlik3.clicked.connect(self.laczeniePdf)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(PolaczPliki)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(PolaczPliki)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 10, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(PolaczPliki)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PolaczPliki)

    def retranslateUi(self, PolaczPliki):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PolaczPliki.setWindowTitle(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Polacz pliki"))
        self.btnPlik1.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Dodaj"))
        self.btnPlik2.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Dodaj"))
        self.btnPlik3.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Plik nr 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Plik nr 2"))

    def openFile1(self):
        pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
        print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
        if pathFileName:
            print("Wybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
            g = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
            return g

    def openFile2(self):
        pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
        print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
        if pathFileName:
            print("Wybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
            h = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
            return h

    def laczeniePdf(self, g,h):
        readerLinkPage1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(g)
        readerLinkPage2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(h)
        writerLinkPage = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        OutputFile = open('FinalOutput.pdf', 'wb')
        writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage1)
        writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage2)
        writerLinkPage.write(OutputFile)
        OutputFile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_MainWindow()
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ... crashes .... With what message? Stacktrace?

Comment: You haven't shown us the code that calls this `laczeniePdf`, or what arguments it passes for `g` and `h`. But as a guess, it's probably passing the values you get back from `openFile1` and `openFile2`, which are two open file objects. And then the first thing you do with them is call `open(g, 'rb')`, which is very suspicious.

Comment: Also, your other two functions take a `self` parameter, which implies that they're methods of some class you haven't shown us—but your `laczeniePdf` does not take a `self` parameter, which implies that, assuming you called it in a reasonable way, `f` is going to be the `self` instance, not whatever you expected `f` to be, and `g` and `h` may be shifted by one from what you expected.

Comment: `laczeniePdf` is called by clicking button:
`self.btnPlik3.clicked.connect(self.laczeniePdf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from   PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import PyPDF2

class Ui_PolaczPliki(object):
    def __init__(self):                     # +++
        self.file_1 = None                  # +++
        self.file_2 = None                  # +++

    def setupUi(self, PolaczPliki):
        PolaczPliki.setObjectName("PolaczPliki")
        PolaczPliki.resize(600, 150)

        self.btnPlik1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 91, 41))
        self.btnPlik1.setObjectName("btnPlik1")
        self.btnPlik1.clicked.connect(self.openFile1)

        self.btnPlik2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 40, 91, 41))
        self.btnPlik2.setObjectName("btnPlik2")
        self.btnPlik2.clicked.connect(self.openFile2)

        self.btnPlik3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(PolaczPliki)
        self.btnPlik3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(165, 90, 91, 41))
        self.btnPlik3.setObjectName("btnPlik3")

        self.btnPlik3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.laczeniePdf(self.file_1, self.file_2)) # +++

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(PolaczPliki)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(PolaczPliki)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 10, 47, 13))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")

        self.retranslateUi(PolaczPliki)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(PolaczPliki)

    def retranslateUi(self, PolaczPliki):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        PolaczPliki.setWindowTitle(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Polacz pliki"))
        self.btnPlik1.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Dodaj Plik nr 1"))
        self.btnPlik2.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Dodaj Plik nr 2"))
        self.btnPlik3.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Start"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Plik nr 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("PolaczPliki", "Plik nr 2"))

    def openFile1(self):
        pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
        print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
        if pathFileName:
            print("\nWybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
            self.file_1 = pathFileName                        # +++
            self.label.setText("{}".format(self.file_1))      # +++
            self.label.adjustSize()                           # +++
            #g = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
            #print("\ng = open(pathFileName, 'rb') =`{}`, \ntype g =`{}` ".format(g, type(g)))
            #return g

    def openFile2(self):
        pathFileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Wybierz plik', '', 'pdf(*.pdf)')
        print("PathFileName-'{}', \n_-'{}'".format(pathFileName, _))
        if pathFileName:
            print("\nWybrany plik: ", pathFileName)
            self.file_2 = pathFileName                        # +++
            self.label_2.setText("{}".format(self.file_2))    # +++ 
            self.label_2.adjustSize()                         # +++
            #h = open(pathFileName, 'rb')
            #print("\nh = open(pathFileName, 'rb') =`{}`, \ntype h =`{}` ".format(h, type(h)))
            #return h

    def laczeniePdf(self, file_1, file_2):                    # +++
        g = open(file_1, 'rb')                                # +++
        h = open(file_2, 'rb')                                # +++
        readerLinkPage1 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(g)
        readerLinkPage2 = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(h)
        writerLinkPage  = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

        OutputFile = open('FinalOutput.pdf', 'wb')
        writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage1)
        writerLinkPage.appendPagesFromReader(readerLinkPage2)
        writerLinkPage.write(OutputFile)
        OutputFile.close() 
        print("\n g=`{}`  +  h=`{}` !!!".format(file_1, file_2))        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_PolaczPliki()                    #Ui_MainWindow()  # +++
    w = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ex.setupUi(w)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it is working. Now I am trying to understand your changes and learn them :)